# Sharepoint .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I have been told I will be let go at the end of the week if I can't figure this out by the end of the day.  I need help in figuring out this issue.  I am trying to create a .aspx page for a sharepoint site.  This is the code I have...

```
<script  runat="server">
Sub submit(Source As Object, e As EventArgs)
   button1.Text="You clicked me!"
End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Click me!" runat="server" OnClick="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting error messages every time I load the page.  I ripped this code off the internet and when I load the page it says:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

Source Error: 

Line 3:     button1.Text="You clicked me!"
Line 4:  End Sub
Line 5:  </script>
Line 6:  
Line 7:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Please help me.  Why am I getting this message?

Comment: Really! Let go at the end of the week. I would of left right there and right then if anybody had said that to me, no matter how much experience I had.

Anyway on to your problem. I don't do sharepoint development. But I seem to remember that you can write code in an .aspx page as long as you configure it in the web.config file.

Just Google what tag you need to added and at what level this should be added.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862025(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't allow inline code in .aspx files by default.  You'll need to change that setting in the web.config if you want to do this, but it's not recommended.  See the link @Mark posted in the comments.

As an alternative, you can create a webpart, and add that to the page.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231519.aspx) for more help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow adding code inside sharepoint pages by adding below lines in the web.config file

```
<PageParserPaths>    
  <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/pages/test.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />    
</PageParserPaths>
```

Where "/pages/test.aspx" is the path of your page , or you can add it as "/_catalogs/masterpage/*" for example to add all masterpages files.